# Is it possible to use a proxy server in redis-cli?

Tags: proxy, redis

From time to time I have to use a proxy server to get access to every web page. Is their a way to tell the redis client (`redis-cli`) to not use the normal connection but to use a proxy?
Or are there any other clients, which allow a proxy?

Comment: Is this Linux or Windows?

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04, so Linux!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SSH tunnel between your machine and the one hosting the Redis server:

`ssh -L 6379:localhost:6379 user@remotehostname`

(6379 is the default port for Redis)

You can also use [Redis Desktop Manager](https://redisdesktop.com/) or [Fastoredis](http://fastoredis.com/), they support SSH tunneling too.

Alternatively, if you do not have the posibility to open an ssh tunnel, you could install [Webdis](http://webd.is/) on the same host than Redis and command Redis from you web browser.